# D3 v4 graph simulation keeps dancing

Tags: force-layout, d3.js

My graph contains a high number of links among a high number of nodes (300 nodes).

Since I upgrade D3 from v3 to v4 and adjusted to the new API and concepts, the graph keeps going in dancing mode.

Here is a brief screencast that shows the effect:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCkBMzs1wWI

I have tried to alternatively remove the forces below:

- collide force
- center force
- change force

.. butt hey don't seem to be the culprit of this issue. The dancing seems to relate to the **link** force only.

This is how my simulation is defined:

```
// force definitions

this.forceCharge =  d3.forceManyBody();
this.forceCenter = d3.forceCenter(1800,1200);
this.forceCollide = d3.forceCollide().radius(10);
this.forceLink =  d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {return d.id;});  

// simulation definition

this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("charge", this.forceCharge)
    .force("link", this.forceLink)
    .force("center", this.forceCenter)
    .force("collide", this.forceCollide)
    .nodes(this.nodes)
    .nodes(this.links)
    .on("tick", this.tick)
    .on("end", this.end);
```

It is to be said that the link strength and distance properties were modified to various settings without any help. I have tried with strength from 0.1 to 1 but that did not help either.

I have also noticed:
the simulation

- The **end** event does not get triggered, meaning that the simulation keeps
  going on for a very long time
- I could call the **simulation.stop()** event. It does stop the dancing but I have to restart it with data changes and the dancing would start again

UPDATE:

- removing the collision detection feature seems to calm down the dancing, but the resulting graph shows that most nodes overlap due tot the fact they have similar connections, creating a geometry that forces them to the same place

[image]

Comment: I doubt, anyone will be able to help you out without seeing the rest of your code. Try setting up an executable demo to fiddle around with.

Comment: Your links are set to your nodes -> `.nodes(this.links)`

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: not really. I had to give up on version 4. Version 3 was more manageable on the graph stability. Still need to try again sometime in the future as I want to use some v4 features